# Build fails when trying to publish to azure app service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to learn azure so i built a simple mvc app and I have a dependency on a class library. 
When trying to publish my app to azure app service I am getting a build failed. When I build my project with visual studio it build just fine. It is saying it cant find my namespaces. I have gone to properties and put copy local to yes and it still doesn't work. Does anyone have any guesses it is .net core 3.1 [image: ure]

output window

[image]

Comment: Generally, there will be no problem when publishing after building success. I think your issues may be not at publish. If it is convenient, you can submit it to Github, and we will solve the problem together. Be careful not to have sensitive information.

Comment: Could be 2 reason. 1) Firewall, port or connection issue (try to publish in local folder) 2) Dependency issue

Comment: @josh can you share what's in the _Output_ window?

Comment: @RyanHill-MSFT output window is now in the post.

Comment: Are both projects targeting .NET Core 3.1 @josh? Perhaps Domain is targeting a .NET Standard? If so, which version?

Comment: you are correct domain is target .net standard 2.0

Comment: hmm that was the issue I had to upgrade to get .net standard 2.1 and then I upgraded the project to that and it deployed fine thank you @RyanHill-MSFT for pointing this out.

Comment: No problem @josh. Glad you got it working.